# How do I get nbit types from fread?

Tags: binary, octave, fread, bit, file-format

I have a file that is a concatenation of K, 17-bit, little endian, unsigned integers. In Matlab I am able to use `fread(fd, K, 'bit17', 'ieee-le')`. How do I read 17 bits off of a file descriptor in `octave`?

Comment: If a file has 48 bits (6 bytes) and you read 17 bits a time, what do you get when you call `fread` a second time? Do you get bits 17-33, or do you get bits 24-40?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file byte by byte then use [`bitget`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Bit-Manipulations.html) to get the binary representation of data and then convert the binary representation  to decimal numbers.

```
nbits = 17;
fd = fopen("myfile","rb");
bytes = fread(fd,Inf,"uint8=>uint8");
n = numel(bytes);
bits = false(8, n);
for k = 1:8
    bits(k,:)=bitget(bytes,k);
end
count = floor(n * 8/nbits);
val = 2.^(0:nbits-1) * reshape(bits(1:count*nbits),nbits,[]);
```